# Prevent Tauri App from Displaying Un-styled Markup in Vite

Tags: css, vite, tauri

When my Tauri app loads, it displays the contents of the `index.html` file for a few seconds before it applies styles from the applicable `css` files. It's kind of cheesy, especially because there are items that should initially be hidden. I can add styles directly to the markup to hide things at first, and then remove them as needed in the `load` event handler, but I wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: How is the CSS being loaded? Is it just `link`s in the `head` if so you shouldn't be getting a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) as far as I know.

Comment: D'oh! Since I'm using Vite, I thought the correct thing to do was to import the stylesheet in the TypeScript file, but I was clearly mistaken. Using a good old link made the problem go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vite has a documentation [section](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css-code-splitting) on how to avoid FOUC:

> Vite automatically extracts the CSS used by modules in an async chunk
> and generates a separate file for it. The CSS file is automatically
> loaded via a `<link>` tag when the associated async chunk is loaded, and
> the async chunk is guaranteed to only be evaluated after the CSS is
> loaded to avoid FOUC.
>
> If you'd rather have all the CSS extracted into a single file, you can
> disable CSS code splitting by setting `build.cssCodeSplit` to `false`.

Alternatively you can force Vite to insert a link in the head:

```
export default defineConfig({
    // ...your config
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                theme: "./assets/your.css" // <-- here
            },
        }
    },
});
```

Also this happens only in `development` run, if you run `production` FOUC should not be the case by design.